# Mobile Layout Not Rendering Width: 100%

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My first attempt using bootstrap on a webapp - this is how it renders on my iPhone.

Why is everything showing up under 100% width?

Example: The top of the page is called dark container, a wrapper with an image embedded, this is the css

```
#darkcontainer {
 height:200px;
 width:100%;
 border: none;
 background-color:whitesmoke;
 text-align:center;
}
```

My guess is that the image beneath(part of a slider) is pushing everything under 100% because it is much larger?  That slider has the following css

```
#slides {
   height:500px;
   width:1065px;
   margin: 0 auto;
      ul.pagination {
          width:100%;
          text-align: center;
            li {
            display:inline-block;
            }
      }
}

        .slides_container {
            width:1065px;
            height:500px;


        }
        .slides_container div {
            width:1065px;
            height:500px;
            display:block;


        }
```

The mailing list looks like it would be different, because there is more of the background color there before it turns white, but that's just... a 100% width wrapper centering the child

```
#autoheightwrap {
   height:auto;
   width:100%;
   background-color:whitesmoke;
}
#mailform {
   height:100%;
   width:600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
        padding: 6px 12px;

 ...
```

[image: SS]

Feel free to look at the website in your browser [here](http://hidden-peak-4186.herokuapp.com/).

Any ideas why it is being rendered this way?

Answer (score 0):

#slides is set at a width of 1065px. This is the culprit that is breaking your site. You'll have to restyle it with a media query targeting mobile.

For a more responsive friendly slideshow, might I suggest [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)?